# Cannot sign the ios app because I dont have the private key

Tags: ios

My Mac has crashed and I dont have a way to get the private key to sign my app and distribute it in the app store. Is there any way to sign my app and put it in to the app store without revoking existing certificates. Because this app is already in the app store, and no way to update it since there is no way to get my private key.

Answer (score 1):

You can revoke certificates and create new ones, and you will still be able to upload the new version to the store. The only thing you need is the same `app bundle id` and the developer account with permissions.